# Custom Function to Count Number of Used Cells in a Column in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a user defined function to count the number of used cells in column A and then multiple this by 10.

Unfortunately, UDF are a completely different coding beast than the macros I usually put together.

```
Function UsedCells() As Long
n = Worksheets("Marginal").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
y = n * 10
End Function
```

This doesn't work -- anyone provide assistance?  Thanks!

EDIT EDIT
This code ended up working based on Christmas' code:

```
Function UsedCells(Col As String) As Long
n = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
UsedCells = n * 10
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is the variable.  So set the name of your function (UsedCells) = to your result:

`UsedCells = n * 10`

EDIT:  Please note this will not recalculate if you use more cells in col A.  To make it calculate dynamically use:

```
Function UsedCells(Col As String) As Long
n = Worksheets("Marginal").Range(Col & ":" & Col).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
UsedCells = n * 10
End Function
```

Then in any given cell in your sheet, place the forumla `=UsedCells("x")` where x is the letter of the Column you want to check.

Working solution:

```
Function UsedCells(Col As String) As Long
UsedCells = Sheets("Marginal").Range(Col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row * 10
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry confused by what you mean?  what do you mean by name

Comment: The name of the Function `UsedCells` is the variable.  I am adding more details to make this more functional for you.

Comment: Alternate method added. Added more detail.

Comment: Hi Christmas, this works but unfortunately counts ALL cells in the column.  I used your code as a skeleton but this worked for me: 
n = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
UsedCells = n * 10